# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.put(Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

My code line causing error:

```
if(!refreshInputStream())
    return;
Workbook workbook = new org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook(datasetInputStream);
```

The refreshInputStream function :

```
private boolean refreshInputStream(){
    if(this.datasetInputStream == null){
        if(this.dataset.length() <= 0){
            return  false;
        }
        try {
            datasetInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(dataset));
        }catch (Exception ex){
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Class variables:

```
public String dataset;
private InputStream datasetInputStream;
```

There is also a function that stores the location(like `C:\Users\Jaysmito\68774.xlsx`) of the file in dataset Variable before reaching the line in which the error is happening.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.put(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.<clinit>(SharedStringsTable.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:63)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:648)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:180)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:286)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:307)
    at App.searchLocal(App.java:238)
    at App.actionPerformed(App.java:207)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

File I am trying to open.

https://rbidocs.rbi.org.in/rdocs/content/docs/68774.xlsx

I am using Apache POI version 4.0.0. I removed the unnecessary GUI code so that the problem is easier to read. What is the problem with my code, and how can I fix it?

My dependencies :

1. xmlbeans-4.0.0.jar
2. poi.ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar
3. commons-codec-1.10.jar
4. commons-compress-1.18.jar
5. commons-collections4-4.2.jar
6. curvesapi-1.04.jar
7. poi-4.0.0.jar
8. poi-ooxml-4.0.0.jar

Comment: You have a mismatch in dependencies. You seem to have a different (incompatible) version of Apache XmlBeans on the classpath than Apache POI requires.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel how can i fix it? i am using intelliJ community 2020

Comment: Check your dependencies and compare them with those documented for Apache POI. Are you using Maven or Gradle? Then include your dependency declaration in your question. Do you manually include them in IntelliJ? Then list all libraries including versions (as text!) in your question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel 1) xmlbeans-4.0.0.jar 2) poi.ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar 3)commons-codec-1.10.jar 4) commons-compress-1.18.jar 5) commons-collections4-4.2.jar 6) curvesapi-1.04.jar 7) poi-4.0.0.jar 8) poi-ooxml-4.0.0.jar

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i manually added these jars as these are this is a very small project

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i am using apache-pio for first time so i dont have much idea about it

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and add them there.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel is it ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your project depends on xmlbeans-4.0.0.jar. Apache POI 4.0.0 requires XMLBeans version 3.0.1, the XMLBeans 4.0.0 version has incompatible changes and cannot be used with the 4.x versions of Apache POI. You either need to downgrade the XMLBeans dependency to 3.0.1 (or at least a 3.x version), or upgrade Apache POI to 5.0.0.

On a related note, you're mixing versions of POI itself as well. You depend on poi.ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar, while all your other POI dependencies are 4.0.0. If you want to use Apache POI 4.x, then use the same 4.x version for all POI dependencies.

In addition, the binary distribution of Apache POI 4.0.0 depends on commons-codec-1.11.jar, not 1.10, and curvesapi-1.05.jar, not 1.04; though those versions are likely compatible.

If this is a new project, I recommend you start with Apache POI 5.0.0, available at https://poi.apache.org/. Use the dependencies included in the binary distribution (in the `lib` and `ooxml-lib` folder of the zip), or better yet, switch to Apache Maven or Gradle, and let that handle your dependencies.

Comment: @MarkRotteeveel I now upgraded to apache poi 5.0 and its working but when i try to open the large xlsx file the app crashes! is there a solution for that>

Comment: @JaysmitoMukherjee Assuming it crashes with an OutOfMemoryError, you either need to increase memory available to your Java process (`-Xmx` parameter), or you need to use the streaming variant of reading Excel sheets instead of trying to read the entire sheet into memory.

Comment: @JaysmitoMukherjee That is an OutOfMemoryError.